# Ruby Lisp Interpreter convert arithmetic symbol?

Tags: ruby, lisp

Essentially I have a evaluate method that takes something like

```
['+','2','3']
```

which would evaluate to 5.

It's currently set up like so,

```
def evaluate(exp)
    f = exp[0]
    if f == '+' then
        return exp[1].to_i + exp[2].to_i
    elsif f == '-' then
        return exp[1].to_i - exp[2].to_i
    elsif f == '*' then
        return exp[1].to_i * exp[2].to_i
    elsif f == '/' then
        return exp[1].to_i / exp[2].to_i
    end
end
```

This works fine, but there has to be a better way to do this without a giant if. Is there a way for me to convert the symbol and use it? How do typically lisp interpreters handle this?

Answer (score 4):

Ruby's all about dynamic programming. In fact this makes your code ridiculously easy:

```
def evaluate(exp)
  exp[1].to_i.send(exp[0], exp[2].to_i)
end
```

It'd be even easier if those tokens were converted on the way in:

```
exp.map! do |token|
  case (token)
  when /\A\-?\d+\z/
    token.to_i
  else
    token
  end
end
```

Then you get this:

```
def evaluate(exp)
  exp[1].send(exp[0], exp[2])
end
```

Now this presumes you're only supplying valid operations, that you're not doing anything absurd, but for trivial cases it works quite well.

If you've converted everything and you're looking to make this more extensible:

```
def evaluate(exp)
  op, *args = exp

  args.reduce(&op.to_sym)
end
```

Then you can do this on arbitrary lists:

```
evaluate([ '+', 2, 1, 3, 4 ])
```

Comment: You don't have to separate the first argument and the rest. You can simply do `[2, 3, 4, 5, 6].inject(:+)
#=> 20`.

Comment: @sawa Yeah, I've added a bit with `reduce` which is functionally the same.

Comment: Generally speaking, `reduce` here blurs the idea of being LISP-like. The AST of adding 3 items won’t be `{:+, 1, 2, 3}`, it is `{:+, 1, {:+, 2, 3}}`. Upvoted, anyway.

Comment: @mudasobwa I was tempted to make it support nested structures but it'd go a little beyond the scope of the question. That isn't much harder to fix.

Answer (score 3):

```
def evaluate(*args)
  operation, *numbers = args
  numbers.map!(&:to_i)
  numbers.first.public_send(operation, numbers.last)
end
```

If you expect more, than two numbers to be used:

```
def evaluate(*args)
  operation, *numbers = args
  numbers.map!(&:to_i).inject(&operation.to_sym)
end

evaluate('+','2','3', 4, 5, 6)
#=> 20
```

You can add an initial value if you need to make sure to always return a `Numeric` from the method (make sure to select any non-zero number, if operation is division or multiplication):

```
def evaluate(*args)
  operation, *numbers = args
  initial_value = %w(/ *).include?(operation) ? 1 : 0
  numbers.map!(&:to_i).inject(initial_value, &operation.to_sym) #<==== note 0
end

evaluate '+'
#=> 0
```

Comment: NB, you must choose an initial value of `1` for multiplication and division.

Comment: You don't have to separate the first argument and the rest. You can simply do `[2, 3, 4, 5, 6].inject(:+)
#=> 20`.

Comment: @sawa first argument is actually an operation, otherwise how would you know, what to pass into `inject`? :)

Comment: Generally speaking, `inject` here blurs the idea of being LISP-like. The AST of adding 3 items won’t be `{:+, 1, 2, 3}`, it is `{:+, 1, {:+, 2, 3}}`. Upvoted, anyway :)

Comment: @mudasobwa: in all Lisps I know, `+` and `*` are n-ary. Not sure about `-` and `/`, though.

Comment: @JörgWMittag indeed, Lisp’s last argument is a list (for `-` and `/` as well.) For some reason, I thought it’s just a handy syntactic sugar for internal AST, but it turns out it is not.

Comment: @mudasobwa `(+ 1 2 3)` translates to `(+ · (1 · (2 · (3 · nil))))`, so it actually does form a tree (although a different one).

Answer (score 1):

Since you ask how this is typically done.

You create a lookup table from operations to their implementation. And then use the first element to lookup an implementation and pass the remaining elements to that function.

Essentially all you need to implement a lisp is

- `evaluate`
- `apply`
- a lookup table

That kernel might even fit into 30–50 lines. I don't think you want us to give you a complete implementation though. That would take all the fun out of writing your own lisp.

I will thus just outline the basic structure…

```
$table = {
  '+' => lambda { |a, b| a + b },
  '-' => lambda { |a, b| a - b },
  '*' => lambda { |a, b| a * b },
  '/' => lambda { |a, b| a.fdiv(b) },
}

def evaluate(args, context = $table)
  # A complete implementation of evaluate would make use of apply ...
  head, *tail = args
  context[head][*tail] 
end

def apply
  # ...
end

puts evaluate(['/', 4, 3])
# => 1.3333333333333333
```

It just so happens that your lisp function names and the corresponding Ruby function names are the same. But that will not always be given, using a lookup table is thus a more typical solution. I mapped the lisp `/` to Ruby's `fdiv` to demonstrate that.

*Fun fact, these first elements are called symbols and actually Ruby uses a very similar mechanism too and hence also has symbols. Internally, Ruby also uses nested lookup tables to organize classes and constants and methods and local variables, et cetera.*

Comment: That way one might build the proper AST, using `#curry` instead of `#[]` in `eval`. This is the best answer here so far.

Comment: Haha, I wanted to leave the complete implementation to them :) essentially all they need is a lookup table with some basic lisp functions and implementations of `eval` and `apply`

Comment: Nice. You shouldn't call it eval, though.

Comment: Updated to include all your comments.

Answer (score 1):

from lisp perspective (common lisp to be precise), you can define `evaluate` as:

```
(defun evaluate (func &rest args)
  (apply func args))
```

in first line you define `evaluate` function to take first argument called `func`, and rest of them (if any) to put in list called `args`.

then you apply list of arguments stored in `args`, to function stored in `func`.

usage examples:

```
(evaluate #'print "some text, printed by function evaluated by my own code!")
=> "some text, printed by function evaluated by my own code!"

(evaluate #'+ 2 3)
=> 5
```

this weird looking `#'` quotes a function name, otherwise "language" would try to evaluate it as it does with all arguments before passing to function.

i also strongly suggest "structure and interpretation of computer programs", at least videos! in the middle there is this great lecture on evaluation, basically heart of (almost) any computer language on 5 whiteboards! (well... green;)

Answer (score 1):

> How do typically lisp interpreters handle this?

Lisp uses *symbols* for global function names. A *symbol* is a named thing with a few associated informations. One of these can be a *function*.

```
CL-USER 42 > (symbol-function '+)
#<Function + 4100044D34>

CL-USER 43 > (funcall (symbol-function '+) 1 2 3 4)
10
```

So for your simple expression evaluation:

```
CL-USER 50 > (defun eval-expression (expression)
               (destructuring-bind (function &rest arguments)
                   expression
                 (apply function arguments)))
EVAL-EXPRESSION

CL-USER 51 > (eval-expression '(+ 1 2 3 4))
10
```

Symbols itself are organized in *packages*, which you can imagine as some kind of specialized table. Packages map names to symbols:

```
CL-USER 52 > (find-symbol "+")
+
:INHERITED
```

If you would want to evaluate a string, you first have to read the string to convert the string to Lisp data. The *reader* will look up the symbols, here `+`, from the current package:

```
CL-USER 53 > (eval-expression (read-from-string "(+ 1 2 3 4)"))
10
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly cleaner version of the same:

```
def evaluate(operation, *numbers)
  numbers.map(&:to_i).reduce(operation)
end

evaluate('+', '2', '3')      # => 5
evaluate('/', '6', '2', '3') # => 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many different solutions and you can chose one that more pretty for you, there are a few from me:

```
exp = ['+','2','3']

def evaluate(exp)
  exp.map(&:to_i).inject(exp.shift)
end 

# > evaluate(exp)
# => 5

def evaluate(operation, *nums)
  nums.map(&:to_i).inject(operation)
end

# > evaluate(*exp)
# => 5
```